# How can I execute a cURL command for twitter in powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, twitter, ssl-certificate

This is what I get so far. I need a curl command for tweets but I can't run this command in powershell.  Basically this works for bash in unix but not in powershell. I am new to powershell and I need help.

```
$command=".\curl.exe --GET 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' --data 'geocode=35.144345%2C33.411364%2C50km' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="nX4pcKmVh97AurzF1vw", oauth_nonce="8b75d7086fcb184fd4558c11fcf64ca1", oauth_signature="Kh%2FrwmLLKT%2FmcjY9mf9z4%2F9duNY%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1398393421", oauth_token="823982814-qi4RnSxugD7nPp5zwWEe8LZ1PxfTLpKsbVk2nR12", oauth_version="1.0"'  --verbose"
invoke-expression $command
```

I also tried `invoke-WebRequest $command`

I have this error:

```
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Closing connection #0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Invoke-Command (or even worse: Invoke-WebRequest with string containing shell command) - try using Start-Process with herestring.
You can read [here](http://huddledmasses.org/the-problem-with-calling-legacy-or-native-apps-from-powershell/) how and why.

Also: since PowerShell v3 there is a way to turn off PowerShell parsing:

```
.\curl.exe --% All your parameters for curl go here
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of curl try this PowerShell module https://github.com/MeshkDevs/InvokeTwitterAPIs

Answer (score 0):

The command is not working at windows because of the single quote. It needs to be double quote in windows. For example `"https://blablabla..."`

For the certificate issue, make sure you have openssl(or other stuffs) installed and the curl is using appropriate certificate. But for testing purpose you can use `-k` parameter to use insecure channel.